# Ordinal Numbers: is it possible to have an isomorphic copy of an ordinal $\alpha$ inside an ordinal $\beta < \alpha$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Could there be a function $f:\alpha \to \beta$ order-preserving and injective such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinal numbers with $\alpha > \beta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. For one thing, what should $f(0)$ be?

Now it may be tempting to let $dom(f)$ be the **nonzero** ordinals to try and fix this. However, this *still* doesn't work: think about where $\omega$ goes. We must have $f(\omega)=n$ for some finite $n$, but then the infinitely-many ordinals $<\omega$ have to be squished into the finitely-many ordinals $<n$.

Indeed, no version of this can happen: **Fodor's lemma** says that if $F$ is a function from ordinals to ordinals (or $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$, or . . . ) which is *regressive* - $F(x)\le x$ - then $F$ is constant on a *stationary set*.

---

EDIT: David Ullrich's comments below have led me to worry that I've interpreted the question incorrectly. I read it as: $f$ maps ordinals to ordinals, and $f$ maps each $\alpha$ to a *smaller* $\beta$. (That's the usual meaning of "$\mapsto$".)

If instead you just are asking about a map from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ - that is, domain $\alpha$, codomain $\beta$ (usually represented by "$f: \alpha\rightarrow\beta$"), then the answer is still no: suppose such an $f$ existed. Since $\beta<\alpha$, we have $\beta\in\alpha$; consider the sequence $$\gamma_0=\beta, \gamma_1=f(\beta), . . . , \gamma_{n+1}=f(\gamma_n).$$ It's easy to show that $\gamma_0>\gamma_1>\gamma_2> . . . $, but this contradicts the well-foundedness of ordinals.

Comment: FWIW, I've also seen 'regressive' functions called 'deflationary'. And $x \leq F(x)$ would be referred to as 'inflationary.'

Comment: @goblin Huh, I've not seen that term before - good to know!

Comment: Glad to be useful :)

Comment: I don't get this at all. Why does "what would $f(0)$ be?" answer anything? Why would $f(\omega)$ have to be $n$? I mean you know I know no set theory but this seems elementary enough...

Comment: I was all set to answer "No. Hint: Show that $f(\gamma)\ge\gamma$ and deduce that $\beta\ge\alpha$." Which seems sort of the reverse of what you said. ???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $f$ is supposed to be a map from ordinals to ordinals, such that $f(\alpha)<\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. If you had such an $f$, what could $f(0)$ be? It would have to be an ordinal $<0$, but there aren't any. Similarly, $f(\omega)$ has to be an ordinal $<\omega$ - well, the ordinals $<\omega$ are exactly the natural numbers.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Note that $f: \alpha\mapsto\beta$, not $f: \alpha\rightarrow\beta$. Mapsto, not rightarrow!

Comment: _Why_ do you say $f$ is a mapping from ordinals to ordinals such that $f(\alpha)<\alpha$? I don't read the question that way at all. Seems to me that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two ordinals, and $f:\alpha\to\beta$ says $f$ is a mapping from $\alpha$ to $\beta$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Because of the symbol "$\mapsto$" used, which denotes the behavior of a function on individual values. Note that it is **not** $f:\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ as you write . . . But I have edited my answer to address that reading of the question as well.

Comment: Oh. Yes, that's what he wrote, and that means what you said. But I wonder if the mapsto was not what he meant. Consider the _title_, which asks about a copy of $\alpha$ inside $\beta$ . That would be $f:\alpha\to\beta$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich See my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant \rightarrow and not \mapsto. My fault. Thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: I bet he really meant \to. I've seen a student consistently write \mapsto in place of \to (in his thesis, too late to fix when I saw it). Also my version is not hard but your reading makes it _so_ trivial... maybe he'll clarify.

Comment: Well it got accepted, so at least now we know it wasn't some third interpretation! :P